# count rows with x value node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have this:

```
if (rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"] == "ACTIVE") {
   console.log("status is " + rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"])
 } else if (rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"] == "INACTIVE") {
    console.log("status is inactive " + rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"])
}
```

and I want to count the number of rows that my table holds with `rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"]` = to inactive, and active. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having more context, I can't tell exactly how you want this information stored. However, it is rather simple to keep a count of occurrences. You can store the number of times you encounter either of these situations in variables.

```js
let numActive = 0;
let numInactive = 0;

if (rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"] == "ACTIVE") {
   numActive++;
   console.log("status is " + rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"])
 } else if (rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"] == "INACTIVE") {
    numInactive++;
    console.log("status is inactive " + rows[i]["SUB_STATUS"])
}

// Do something with these values
console.log('Number of active:', numActive);
console.log('Number of inactive:', numInactive)
```